# Mention list and emoji top position (Draft.js)

Tags: reactjs, emoji, draftjs, mention, draft-js-plugins

Will you please help me how I can change its position from bottom to top?
I want to show mention list on top of the text instead of the bottom.
The same question about emoji list.

[Example link.](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/emoji)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was my solution fit for your issue? Maybe I incorrect understand your question.

Comment: this is what i use, not showing list on top

`
return {
        left: settings.decoratorRect.left + 'px',
        top: settings.decoratorRect.top - 40 + 'px', // change this value (40) for manage the distance between cursor and bottom edge of popover
        display: 'block',
        transform: 'scale(1) translateY(-100%)', // transition popover on the value of its height
        transformOrigin: '1em 0% 0px',
        transition: 'all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.2, 0.2, 1)',
        position: 'absolute'
      };
`

Comment: Check this too: https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/issues/665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it with `positionSuggestions` configuration option. This option available for both `mention` and `emoji` plugins.

Excerpt from documentation:

> **positionSuggestions**
>
> The function can be used to manipulate the position of the popover containing the suggestions. It receives one
>   object as arguments containing the visible rectangle surrounding the
>   decorated search string including the @. In addition the object
>   contains prevProps, prevState, state & props. An object should be
>   returned which can contain all sorts of styles. The defined properties
>   will be applied as inline-styles.

In `constructor` you should create plugin this way:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin({
    positionSuggestions: (settings) => {
      return {
        left: settings.decoratorRect.left + 'px',
        top: settings.decoratorRect.top - 40 + 'px', // change this value (40) for manage the distance between cursor and bottom edge of popover
        display: 'block',
        transform: 'scale(1) translateY(-100%)', // transition popover on the value of its height
        transformOrigin: '1em 0% 0px',
        transition: 'all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.2, 0.2, 1)'
      };
    }
  });
}
```

And `render` method:

```
render() {
  const { MentionSuggestions } = this.mentionPlugin;
  const plugins = [this.mentionPlugin];

  return (
    <div className={editorStyles.editor} onClick={this.focus}>
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        plugins={plugins}
        ref={(element) => { this.editor = element; }}
      />
      <div style={{ visibility: this.state.suggestions.length ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>
        <MentionSuggestions
          onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
          suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
          onAddMention={this.onAddMention}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/w62x3472k7

Comment: I just used you css function but using this css it is not showing mention list on top.
i've attach image you can check it is coming down, i can't see even

Comment: Strange. For me, it works. Check this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/x2r59zo4j4 I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, your example working perfect, is there any way to stop mention popup? so that i can check it's div by inspecting element.

b/c when i lose focus it's html gone

Comment: I think, that it is possible only by rewriting source code of popup component.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, need one more `position: 'fixed'`.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, need one more position: 'fixed'. Also for future people, check [this](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/issues/665) which is a beautiful solution

Comment: Thanks @HongboMiao using  **position: 'fixed'** it's working now in my end.
Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Guys, your solution does not work in a dailog if i use editor in it.

Comment: Hi @MikhailShabrikov Your possitionSuggestions works great. But if you type a non existing suggestions name letter by letter, you can see the suggestion popup flickering. For example type @ dontexist letter by letter.

Comment: @KarthikAmar You can fix it by wrapping `MentionSuggestions` component to the `div` and apply `visibility: hidden` style on the `div` if suggestions is an empty array. I updated the answer and the sandbox.